# Is there a way to play audio files in Windows 7 at random intervals?

Tags: windows-7, audio

Can I use a task manager or something that I can schedule to play audio files at random intervals i.e. 30 min, 1 hr, 40 min throughout the day?

Answer (score 1):

What about using a piece of VBScript to play the audio file, you can schedule this using task scheduler.  For example.

1. Create C:\testmusic\
2. Add the music files you wish to play to the directory.  Could be elsewhere but this is a working example.
3. Create the following file "test.vbs" and add the following content:

   Dim oPlayer : Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")

   oPlayer.URL = WScript.Arguments(0)

   oPlayer.controls.play

   While oPlayer.playState <> 1 ' 1 = Stopped

   WScript.Sleep 100

   Wend

   oPlayer.close

You could then create a scheduled task as follows to run the script.

Note: The parameter is the audio file.

[image]